# Angular 6. How to test injected components

Tags: javascript, angular, testing, angular-test

I have a FAB component separated in 3 parts: trigger component, actions component and main component, gathering all together.

Trigger and Actions components have an injected parent like this:

```
constructor(
  @Inject(forwardRef(() => FabSpeedDialComponent)) private _parent: 
FabSpeedDialComponent,
  private renderer: Renderer
) { }
```

Parent have circular dependency to it's actions: `@ContentChild(FabSpeedDialActionsComponent) _childActions: FabSpeedDialActionsComponent;`

It works great, but I have a problem with testing this behaviour. As an exaple, there's test for `actions` component:

```
import { async, ComponentFixture, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';

import { FabSpeedDialActionsComponent } from './fab-speed-dial-actions.component';

describe('FabSpeedDialActionsComponent', () => {
  let component: FabSpeedDialActionsComponent ;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<FabSpeedDialActionsComponent>;

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [FabSpeedDialActionsComponent]
    })
      .compileComponents();
  }));

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(FabSpeedDialActionsComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  fit('should create', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

It fails with this error:

> Error:
>   StaticInjectorError(DynamicTestModule)[FabSpeedDialActionsComponent ->
>   FabSpeedDialComponent]:    StaticInjectorError(Platform:
>   core)[FabSpeedDialActionsComponent -> FabSpeedDialComponent]: 
>       NullInjectorError: No provider for FabSpeedDialComponent!

Even if I try to add it to declarations it still fails.

Comment: [Documentation](https://angular.io/guide/testing#component-with-a-dependency)

Comment: @trichetriche there's about inectable services, not components. No single word about `forwardRef` components.

Comment: You apparently missed the part about mocking.

Comment: Did you try adding FabSpeedDialComponent to the providers list for the TestBed?  ie: after declarations, add a comma and then a new line with `providers: [FabSpeedDialComponent]`.  You may also want to mock FabSpeedDialComponent and insert a spy/mock instead.